# How to change version of node used in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins

Builds have started failing on my Jenkins server with error messages similar to

```
error file-selector@0.1.12: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 8". Got "6.17.1"
```

When I log into the server and run

```
nvm ls
```

I see the following;

[image]

How do I configure Jenkins to use the default version of node (v8.17.0 for this server) rather than the lts/boron version v6.17.1 which it's picking up?

**Extra information**

I did a little more digging.

```
$ node -v
v6.17.1
$ sudo node -v
v6.17.1
$ sudo su
# node -v
v8.1.2
```

So - the normal user is picking up the wrong version, while the root superuser is picking up the correct one. To get the normal user to pick up the correct version, I ran

```
$ sudo nvm ls
sudo: nvm: command not found
```

I *believe* that if I can get the standard node version to be v8.1.2 for all users, it will work. But how to do that...

Comment: `node -v` will tell you which node version your system is actually using, which I'm pretty sure, is what Jenkins is using.  `nvm alias default stable` is what I have used in the past to change the default node version after a new node been installed.

Comment: @JM-AGMS I've added some extra information above showing the results of various nvm commands / users. Does that help?

Comment: You probably installed node while logged in as root, try installing it again as a normal user. As a hint, `which node` will tell you the install path.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Thank you - I will try that this evening.